# Connect to a server multiple times in java using one computer

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server

I am creating a snake multiplayer game in java and I want to test the server
but I have only one computer, do you know what should I do ?

if you don't know too, you can see my main server code and main client code down here and you can just
tell me if it works or not.

I use Json for server and client to trade information
and the game starts with 4 snakes with different colors and if a snake eats apples, becomes big and bigger. snakes can eat smaller snakes

I want to see all 4 snakes' moves using one computer

server code:

```
  package com.company;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.ServerSocket;
   import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8888);

    Board board = new Board();

    Socket socket1 = server.accept();

    Thread receiveThread1;
    Thread receiveThread2;
    Thread receiveThread3;
    Thread receiveThread4;

    Thread sendThread1;
    Thread sendThread2;
    Thread sendThread3;
    Thread sendThread4;

    Send sender1 = new Send(socket1,board);
    sender1.out.writeUTF("snake1");
    sender1.out.flush();

    Send sender2 = new Send(server,board);
    sender2.out.writeUTF("snake2");
    sender2.out.flush();

    Send sender3 = new Send(server,board);
    sender3.out.writeUTF("snake3");
    sender3.out.flush();

    Send sender4 = new Send(server,board);
    sender4.out.writeUTF("snake4");
    sender4.out.flush();

    while (true){
        receiveThread1 = new Thread(new Receive(socket1,board));
        receiveThread2 = new Thread(new Receive(socket2,board));
        receiveThread3 = new Thread(new Receive(socket3,board));
        receiveThread4 = new Thread(new Receive(socket4,board));

        receiveThread1.start();
        receiveThread2.start();
        receiveThread3.start();
        receiveThread4.start();

        receiveThread1.join();
        receiveThread2.join();
        receiveThread3.join();
        receiveThread4.join();

        board.update();

        sendThread1 = new Thread(new Send(socket1,board));
        sendThread2 = new Thread(new Send(socket2,board));
        sendThread3 = new Thread(new Send(socket3,board));
        sendThread4 = new Thread(new Send(socket4,board));

        sendThread1.start();
        sendThread2.start();
        sendThread3.start();
        sendThread4.start();

        sendThread1.join();
        sendThread2.join();
        sendThread3.join();
        sendThread4.join();
    }
}
}
```

main client code:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;

 import java.awt.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

 import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

   public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    
    //Game game = new Game();
    ShowBoard m = new ShowBoard();

    m.CreateLayout();
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8888);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
    Snake snake = m.board.snake1;
    String name = in.readUTF();
    snake.name = name;
    switch (name){
        case "snake1":
            snake.direction = 'r';
            break;
        case "snake2":
            snake.direction = 'd';
            break;
        case "snake3":
            snake.direction = 'l';
            break;
        case "snake4":
            snake.direction = 'u';
            break;
    }

    byte[] tile;

    while (true) {
        switch (snake.direction){
            case 'l':
                out.writeUTF("{\"action\":\"move\",\"direction\":\"left\",\"snakeName\":\"" + snake.name + "\"}");
                out.flush();
                break;
            case 'r':
                out.writeUTF("{\"action\":\"move\",\"direction\":\"right\",\"snakeName\":\"" + snake.name + "\"}");
                out.flush();
                break;
            case 'u':
                out.writeUTF("{\"action\":\"move\",\"direction\":\"up\",\"snakeName\":\"" + snake.name + "\"}");
                out.flush();
                break;
            case 'd':
                out.writeUTF("{\"action\":\"move\",\"direction\":\"down\",\"snakeName\":\"" + snake.name +"\"}");
                out.flush();
                break;
        }
        tile = in.readNBytes(625);
        m.sidepanel.scoreForSnake1 = in.readInt();
        m.sidepanel.scoreForSnake2 = in.readInt();
        m.sidepanel.scoreForSnake3 = in.readInt();
        m.sidepanel.scoreForSnake4 = in.readInt();
        m.board.convertTo2D(tile);
        m.board.repaint();
        m.sidepanel.repaint();
        sleep(1000);

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: If you want to be able to serve multiple clients in your server, you have to *accept* multiple clients in your server, typically in a loop. See the Custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial. NB [tag:awt] has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just start the client four times on your Computer.

Comment: @JRSofty No example is required. The same code that connects once will connect *N* times, even with this incorrectly written server. The OP is labouring under some misapprehension.